# Does the google play default waiting room have a timeout option?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I am using the Google Play waiting room to wait for other players to join, by calling

```
MyActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, RC_WAITING_ROOM);
```

I would like this waiting activity to finish after a certain time, for example, after one minute waiting, I would like it to finish and leave the room with a message explaining the timeout.
Is this possibility provided by Google Play or I would have to create my own timer to deal with it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented my own timer for it.